# Scrapy: Does not collect data from all pages

Tags: python, scrapy

Help please to understand what the error is.
Go to pages ... /?start = 0, /?start = 25, /?start = 50
Collects data only from the last page (50).
My code:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy import Request
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

from ..items import GetDomainsItem


def pages_range(start, step):
    stop = 50
    r = start
    while r <= stop:
        yield r
        r += step

class GetUrlDelDomSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'get_domains'

    allowed_domains = ["member.expireddomains.net"]

    paginate = pages_range(0, 25)

    start_urls = list(map(lambda i: 'https://member.expireddomains.net/domains/expiredcom201612/?start=%s' % i, paginate))
    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(start_url, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formnumber=1,
                                        formdata={'login': 'xxx', 'password': '*****', 'rememberme': '1'},
                                        callback=self.parse_login,
                                        dont_filter=True)
    def parse_login(self, response):
       if b'The supplied login information are unknown.' not in response.body:
          item = GetDomainsItem()
          for each in response.selector.css('table.base1 tbody '):
              item['domain'] = each.xpath('tr/td[@class="field_domain"]/a/text()').extract()
              return item
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return item` in your `parse_login` method breaks the loop:

```
for each in response.selector.css('table.base1 tbody '):
    item['domain'] = each.xpath('tr/td[@class="field_domain"]/a/text()').extract()
    return item
      ^
```

So you should **create** an item and **yield** it in each iteration of your loop:

```
for each in response.selector.css('table.base1 tbody '):
    item = GetDomainsItem()
    item['domain'] = each.xpath('tr/td[@class="field_domain"]/a/text()').extract()
    yield item
```